# What is the proper regex for capturing everything after "String" and between two delimeters ('=' and and non alphanumeric))

Tags: regex

```
Details={
  AwsEc2SecurityGroup={GroupName=m.com-rds, OwnerId=123, VpcId=vpc-123, 
    IpPermissions=[{FromPort=3306, ToPort=3306, IpProtocol=tcp, IpRanges=[{CidrIp=1.1.1.1/32}, {CidrIp=2.2.2.2/32}, {CidrIp=0.0.0.0/0}, {CidrIp=3.3.3.3/32}], 
    UserIdGroupPairs=[{UserId=123, GroupId=sg-123abc}]}], IpPermissionsEgress=[{IpProtocol=-1, IpRanges=[{CidrIp=0.0.0.0/0}]}], GroupId=sg-123abc}}, 
    Region=us-east-1, Id=arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:security-group/sg-123abc}]
}
```

I want to capture exactly `arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:security-group/sg-123abc` in this example. Generically, I want to capture the value of `Id` regardless of placement. My current solution is `/Details={.*Id=(.*\w)/`, but this only works if it's the last object in the data. How can I take into account the following potential scenario:

`Id=arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123:security-group/sg-123abc, Thing=123abc}]`

Comment: What is the rule for determining where the string of interest terminates? Evidently it cannot include a comma. That's one. What other characters, if any, terminate it? What do you mean by, "the last object in the data"? Examples are often helpful in elaborating questions, but they are rarely sufficient in themselves to allow readers gain a complete understanding of the question. Be precise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pattern with 2 times `.*` which will first match till the end of the line/string (depending on if the dot matches a newline) and it will backtrack to match the last occurrence where this part of the pattern `Id=(.*\w)` can match.

If you want to use a capture group, you can make the format and the allowed characters a bit more specific:

```
\bId=(\w+(?:[:\/-]\w+)+)
```

The pattern in parts

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `Id=` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  - `(?:[:\/-]\w+)+` Repeat 1+ times either `:` `/` `-` and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA9v0Z/1)

Or if you know that it starts with `Id=arn:`

```
\bId=(arn:[\w:\/-]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5R8orW/1)

Note that you don't have to escape the `\/` only when the delimiters of the regex are forward slashes, but there is no language tagged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use look-behind to check that there is the `Id=` prefix, and then match anything that is not a space, comma or closing brace:

[`(?<=\bId=)[^,}\s]*`](https://regex101.com/r/ZC5akN/1)